# Different link for each image on slideshow

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript for a slideshow and I want that each image on that slideshow to have a different link. I just added that href tag for each one but it doesn't work... Here's the script:

```
window.addEventListener('load', slideShow, false);

function slideShow() {

    var globals = {
        slideDelay: 4000,
        fadeDelay: 35,
        wrapperID: "slideShowImages",
        buttonID: "slideShowButton",
        buttonStartText: "Start Slides",
        buttonStopText: "Stop Slides",
        buttonObject: null,
        slideImages: [],
        slideShowID: null,
        slideShowRunning: true,
        slideIndex: 0
    }

    initializeGlobals();

    if (insufficientSlideShowMarkup()) {
        return;
    }

    if (globals.slideImages.length == 1) {
        return;
    }

    initializeSlideShowMarkup();

    globals.wrapperObject.addEventListener('click', toggleSlideShow, false);

    if (globals.buttonObject) {
        globals.buttonObject.addEventListener('click', toggleSlideShow, false);
    }

    startSlideShow();


    function initializeGlobals() {
        globals.wrapperObject = (document.getElementById(globals.wrapperID) ? document.getElementById(globals.wrapperID) : null);
        globals.buttonObject = (document.getElementById(globals.buttonID) ? document.getElementById(globals.buttonID) : null);

        if (globals.wrapperObject) {
            globals.slideImages = (globals.wrapperObject.querySelectorAll('img') ? globals.wrapperObject.querySelectorAll('img') : []);
        }
    }

    function insufficientSlideShowMarkup() {
        if (!globals.wrapperObject) {
            if (globals.buttonObject) {
                globals.buttonObject.style.display = "none";
            }
            return true;
        }

        if (!globals.slideImages.length) {
            if (globals.wrapperObject) {
                globals.wrapperObject.style.display = "none";
            }

            if (globals.buttonObject) {
                globals.buttonObject.style.display = "none";
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    function initializeSlideShowMarkup() {
        var slideWidthMax = maxSlideWidth();
        var slideHeightMax = maxSlideHeight();

        globals.wrapperObject.style.position = "relative";
        globals.wrapperObject.style.overflow = "hidden";
        globals.wrapperObject.style.width = slideWidthMax + "px";
        globals.wrapperObject.style.height = slideHeightMax + "px";

        var slideCount = globals.slideImages.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < slideCount; i++) {
            globals.slideImages[i].style.opacity = 0;
            globals.slideImages[i].style.position = "absolute";
            globals.slideImages[i].style.top = (slideHeightMax - globals.slideImages[i].getBoundingClientRect().height) / 2 + "px";
            globals.slideImages[i].style.left = (slideWidthMax - globals.slideImages[i].getBoundingClientRect().width) / 2 + "px";
        }

        globals.slideImages[0].style.opacity = 1;

        if (globals.buttonObject) {
            globals.buttonObject.textContent = globals.buttonStopText;
        }
    }

    function maxSlideWidth() {
        var maxWidth = 0;
        var maxSlideIndex = 0;
        var slideCount = globals.slideImages.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < slideCount; i++) {
            if (globals.slideImages[i].width > maxWidth) {
                maxWidth = globals.slideImages[i].width;
                maxSlideIndex = i;
            }
        }

        return globals.slideImages[maxSlideIndex].getBoundingClientRect().width;
    }

    function maxSlideHeight() {
        var maxHeight = 0;
        var maxSlideIndex = 0;
        var slideCount = globals.slideImages.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < slideCount; i++) {
            if (globals.slideImages[i].height > maxHeight) {
                maxHeight = globals.slideImages[i].height;
                maxSlideIndex = i;
            }
        }

        return globals.slideImages[maxSlideIndex].getBoundingClientRect().height;
    }

    function startSlideShow() {
        globals.slideShowID = setInterval(transitionSlides, globals.slideDelay);
    }

    function haltSlideShow() {
        clearInterval(globals.slideShowID);
    }

    function toggleSlideShow() {
        if (globals.slideShowRunning) {
            haltSlideShow();
            if (globals.buttonObject) {
                globals.buttonObject.textContent = globals.buttonStartText;
            }
        } else {
            startSlideShow();
            if (globals.buttonObject) {
                globals.buttonObject.textContent = globals.buttonStopText;
            }
        }
        globals.slideShowRunning = !(globals.slideShowRunning);
    }

    function transitionSlides() {
        var currentSlide = globals.slideImages[globals.slideIndex];

        ++(globals.slideIndex);
        if (globals.slideIndex >= globals.slideImages.length) {
            globals.slideIndex = 0;
        }

        var nextSlide = globals.slideImages[globals.slideIndex];

        var currentSlideOpacity = 1;
        var nextSlideOpacity = 0;.
        var opacityLevelIncrement = 1 / globals.fadeDelay;
        var fadeActiveSlidesID = setInterval(fadeActiveSlides, globals.fadeDelay);

        function fadeActiveSlides() {
            currentSlideOpacity -= opacityLevelIncrement;
            nextSlideOpacity += opacityLevelIncrement;

            if (currentSlideOpacity >= 0 && nextSlideOpacity <= 1) {
                currentSlide.style.opacity = currentSlideOpacity;
                nextSlide.style.opacity = nextSlideOpacity;
            } else {
                currentSlide.style.opacity = 0;
                nextSlide.style.opacity = 1;
                clearInterval(fadeActiveSlidesID);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: " I just added that href tag" Where? I do not see it.

Comment: I did it on the html, the js is on another file.

Answer (score 0):

arry=[link1,link1,link1,link1]

create anchor and iterate through array and assign href attribute the value of array element which u want and then insert your slide

Comment: And where do I do that?